# Joining two dataframes using paired index keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes from which I've identified match candidates to merge together into one dataframe. Each original dataframe has its own index and the indeces do not correspond to each other (and no other columns to merge on). However, I have an array of paired indeces indicating which individual record pairs should be joined together. I have been unable to find any resources for this type of merge https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html.

The method I've come up with is clunky and slow, and I'm sure there's a better way.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                    index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7'],
                    'B': ['B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'],
                    'C': ['C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7'],
                    'D': ['D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7']},
                    index=[4, 5, 6, 7])

# The array of paired index keys
matches = np.array([(3,4),
                   (1,5),
                   (0,6),
                   (2,7)])

keys = {i[0]: i[1] for i in matches}

merged = pd.DataFrame()
for key, value in keys.items():
    left = df1.loc[[key]].reset_index()
    right = df2.loc[[value]].reset_index()

    together = pd.concat([left, right], axis = 1)
    merged = merged.append(together)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't want the `index` named columns in your dataframe, converting your array of paired indexes into a dictionary and using the `rename` function can also be an approach:

```
matches = {3:4,1:5,0:6,2:7}
print(pd.concat([df1.rename(index=matches),df2],
                axis=1))
```

However, if you want to keep `matches` declared as a `np.array`, the above code will do the trick:

```
matches = np.array([(3,4),
                   (1,5),
                   (0,6),
                   (2,7)])
print(pd.concat([df1.rename(index=dict(matches)),df2], axis=1))
```

In both cases, output will be:

```
    A   B   C   D   A   B   C   D
4  A3  B3  C3  D3  A4  B4  C4  D4
5  A1  B1  C1  D1  A5  B5  C5  D5
6  A0  B0  C0  D0  A6  B6  C6  D6
7  A2  B2  C2  D2  A7  B7  C7  D7
```

Comment: I like idea too.  +1

Comment: You can short to using OP matches array using this `pd.concat([df1.rename(index=dict(matches)),df2], axis=1)`

Comment: Oh, silly me indeed! Just edited my answer to use `index=matches` instead of `index={3:4,1:5,0:6,2:7}`. Also added your suggestion to keep matches as an array. However, I highly recommend using a `dict`, unless there is a good reason in the real code for don't doing so, since using the array in this approach will force the code to execute one more operation (converting from `array` to `dict`), which, depending on the case, can impact in the code execution time.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, sort the dataframes according to matches using `reindex`, then `reset_index` and `pd.concat` dataframes:

```
d1 = df1.reindex(matches[:,0]).reset_index()
d2 = df2.reindex(matches[:,1]).reset_index()

pd.concat([d1,d2], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   index   A   B   C   D  index   A   B   C   D
0      3  A3  B3  C3  D3      4  A4  B4  C4  D4
1      1  A1  B1  C1  D1      5  A5  B5  C5  D5
2      0  A0  B0  C0  D0      6  A6  B6  C6  D6
3      2  A2  B2  C2  D2      7  A7  B7  C7  D7
```